# Conditional sums in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a very large table of data in Excel with columns

```
Region      Year      Department      Role      Effort
```

I want to create another table that shows an agregate view of this data across regions and role. So it would just have columns

```
Year      Department      Effort
```

I can manually create the second table with all combinations of `Year` and `Department`.
 But how to populate the `Effort` column based on the data from my first table?

Comment: You might want to consider using a pivot table.

Comment: Other orion could be `SUMIFS`

Comment: If you show some example Data to explain the relation between columns

Comment: I can't use a pivot table as I need to pull in other metrics along side effort from other sheets. Hence I need to get the data into anothe table.

Comment: I tried SUMIFS but could get it to work. What would the logic be?

Comment: I tried using the formula in the effort column in the aggregate table:

Comment: I tried using the formula in the effort column in the aggregate table: = SUMIF(Table1[@Effort]],[@year],Table1[@year],[@Department],Table1[@Department])     This is where Table1 is the table that shows the more granular data set broken down by role etc and the aggregate table is where I am look to get the summary across roles etc.

Comment: A pivot table give me what I need but I can't join it to the other data. For example in the pivot table I get year and department all in the first column as expandable items rather than as column headings with the values in the table.

Comment: Any ideas what else I can try?

Comment: I am not sure how to share example data here as I can't even get a new line without having to enter a new comment

Comment: Edit your question and write the example and explain what you expect and which formula did not work for you